# How to make tabs and toogle button placing in same row using css?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

How can I place tabs and toggle buttons in the same row?

[image]

Please see the attached image also added my code below. could someone help me with this

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Label1">
    <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 10px">
      <mat-button-toggle-group #toggleGroup1="matButtonToggleGroup">
        <mat-button-toggle value="Angular Material UI">
          Angular Material UI
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="React Material UI">
          React Material UI
        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
      <br />
      You have selected : {{ toggleGroup1.value }}
    </div>
    test 1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Label2"> test 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Label3"> test3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active-qjz3uc?file=app/tabs-template-label-example.html)

i'm bad in CSS could someone advise how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**(Quick fix, take a look at `BUT` section, before using it)**
Adding those two css rules should help:

```
.mat-tab-group {
  flex-direction: row !important;
}
.ng-trigger-translateTab div {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

**BUT:** Using `!important` is a bad practice, and overriding the default behaviour of the components is also a bad practice. (however, above snippet will not work without `!important` because we are trying to rewrite the generic behaviour).
For a good practice I would advice to look inside the components, and try to think how you change their css rules or maybe better arrange or nest them more properly, so they look in a way you want them to look.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry this won't help me. if I add this css it broke my UI.is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I have added those styles here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active-ryhhxx?file=app%2Ftabs-template-label-example.css
Looks like nothing is broken

Comment: see tab content where its displaying in screen"

You have selected :
test 1"

Comment: Does this one look ok? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active-ryhhxx?file=app%2Ftabs-template-label-example.html,app%2Ftabs-template-label-example.css

Comment: sorry only the toggle button should be placed in the same row and same time tab content should display down not on same row

Comment: You can't do that with the currect structure, as those two elements (toggle and  `you-have-chosen` text row) are inside one `mat-tab-body` component. In order to achieve the design you want you need to brake this component into two parts, one: toggle, second: you-have-chosen text row. Then you can place toggle in a same row with tabs, and the `you-have-chosen text row` below it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to give your div :

```
<div style="d-flex-inline">
```

That means display flex inline.